# CASE WHEN is not working properly on created columns in SQL

Tags: sql, case

I created a new column (height_m) by dividing height_cm by 100 (height_cm is an original column in my table):

`height_cm / 100.0 AS height_m`

The new column showed correct answers (156 --> 1.56)

Then based on this height_m column, I want to classify the height as "short" or "tall".
So for this, I had this argument

`CASE WHEN 'height_m' >= 1.0 then 1 else 0 end as is_tall`

I noticed that it is not returning the correct boolean.
Some height_m have values of 1.56 or even 2.21 but I would get a 0 for all of them.

I figured out that maybe I need to remove the quotation marks such that it looks like:
`CASE WHEN height_m >= 1.0 then 1 else 0 end as is_tall`

But an error appears and says: 'There is no column named height_m'
Hence it seems like I can only make the CASE WHEN argument when I quote the created column.

To investigate further I did the following:

I tried directly classifying height_cm (built-in column) using the ff code:

`CASE WHEN height_cm >= 100 then 1 else 0 end as is_tall`

In this case I notice that it correctly classified my height as tall or not.

Now the question is, why is my classification wrong when I created the new column vs when I classify the values under the original column?

I am very new to SQL so I'm sorry this question is dumb.

Thank you for explaining in advance.

I wanted to know how I could get an accurate result from a column that I created after doing some formulas on the original values.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  First, the term `'height_m'` is actually a *string* literal, not the alias `height_m`.  Second, an alias defined within a given `SELECT` clause cannot be reused at the same level.  Here is a potentially valid version of what you were trying to do:

```sql
SELECT height_m / 100.0 AS height_m,
       CASE WHEN height_m / 100.0 >= 1.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_tall
FROM yourTable;
```

In this case, we simply are repeating the expression for `height_m` in the `CASE` expression.  Note that we could also subquery and then directly use `height_m` in the outer query:

```sql
SELECT height_m, CASE WHEN height_m >= 1.0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_tall
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, height_cm / 100.0 AS height_m
    FROM yourTable t
) s;
```

Comment: Hello, Tim! Thank you for your quick response.I understand now, I simply cannot create an alias column then make a CASE WHEN argument out of it. I simply have to copy paste the entire formula then do the CASE WHEN with it.

Comment: Just a note, since no dbms is specified, I'd suggest qualifying the derived table's `*` - so the query becomes standard compliant - and more portable.

Comment: @jarlh Good point, especially for Oracle.